# How do I use substring method in ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, substring

I made a program in java like this:

```
class substr{
  public static void main (String[]args){
    int n=1;
    String s1="";
    String s2="          ";
    while (n<=5){
      System.out.println(s2.substring(n,5)+n+s1+n);
      s1=s1+"  ";
      s2=s2+" ";
      n++;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't make use of substring in ruby, so I wanted to know if there is some way. I read about regex, but you don't use it in a program like this.

Comment: You are looking for the slice method. Google Ruby string class slice. PS have a look at the shovel operator << instead of + as well, not to mention padstr which would take most of that code out. Tere will be java equivalents as well.

Comment: Ruby also has - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Answer (score 0):

You can use array notation to substring an string. In your case, something like `s2[n,5]`.